# How to access a single, visible element from an array of objects being displayed by will_paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a rails web app which manages students and courses. I have a courses controller which has the following index action:

```
  def index

    @courses = Course.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 1)
    @courses.order(:startDate)
    #@thisCourse = Course.find(params[:page])

  end
```

So pretty standard except for one thing - all the details of a single course are shown on one page and to show the details of the next course, you move to the next page of the pagination.

The problem is that in this index page showing the details of 1 course per pagination, I have a "Sign Up!" button which when pressed needs to create a a new record in the 'signups' db table which has the automated 'id' field and then the 'user_id' and the 'course_id' fields.

The 'user_id' is easy to find (current_user.id).

The 'course_id' is proving difficult. I imagine that pressing the Signup button should send the course_id to the signups_controller where a create function can do the work. But how can I get this exact course ID from the index page to the signups_controller's create action?

As you can see in the code I pasted from the courses_controller's index action,the '@thisCourse' variable has been commented out because I have found no way to define which course is currently being shown on the page.

The fields are rendered by the will_paginate Gem so I'm not sure how it's generating the fields but I was thinking that maybe I could create a named hidden field which includes the course_id and use that when the sign up button is pressed, however I'm not sure how to go about it.

Does anybody have any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use `show` method (output one course) instead of `index`(output all courses) method, that will always get your course `id` through `params`.

Comment: Thanks, I had thought of that but to reach 'show' method I would have to use index as, well, an index and then have the user click into the course. Maybe this is more logical but I don't know. I feel like it's an unnecessary click for the user.

Comment: @user3535074: This seems more convenient – user can find any course within one click instead of searching from 1 to n pages to find the course he wants.

Comment: I understand what you mean but the courses are going to be few in number - only 2 or 3 maximum will be future courses which students can sign up for and they're always the first courses you see. You may be right anyhow... The course details HTML is being generated by form_for. Maybe if I create a submit button within form_for that calls for a particular controller and action it would pass the signup controller all the details of the course. I'm not sure if its possible - will have to read up...

Answer (score 0):

Basically I changed my approach to the problem. I removed the button which was supposed to call the signups_controller and create the new record in the signups table. This button was replaced by adjusting the form_for helper so that it's submit button would send all the necessary data to the signups_controller (including the id value which was added to the form as a hidden field).

The form ended up looking like this:

```
<%= form_for course, :url => {:controller => "signups", :action => "create"}, :method => "post" do |f| %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag :course_id, course.id %>

    <%= f.label :"Course Title" %>
    <%= f.text_field :courseTitle, class: 'form-control' %>

    + all fields included in the form....

    <%= f.submit "Sign Up!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

This parameter of form_for defines which controller and which action in that controller is the submission target:

```
:url => {:controller => "signups", :action => "create"}
```

and this parameter overwrites the default http action (default is PATCH but in this case I wanted to POST i.e. create a new entry in the signups table):

```
:method => "post"
```

I'm not sure if this is a very quick and dirty solution but technically it gets the necessary data to the correct destination controller.